# /var/lib/plocate/plocate.db: has version 4294967295, expected 0 or 1; please rebuild it

Tags: linux, compiling, source-code

No matter how many times I rebuild the plocate db I get:

```
/var/lib/plocate/plocate.db: has version 4294967295, expected 0 or 1; please rebuild it.
```

How in the world did I manage this??

```
/sbin/updatedb.plocate:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007f1c7d4000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x0000007f1c6c0000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000007f1c490000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x0000007f1c3f0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000007f1c3c0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007f1c210000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000003000000000)
/bin/plocate:
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00000077e07be000)
    liburing.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liburing.so.2 (0x00000077e0760000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1 (0x00000077e0690000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00000077e0460000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000077e0430000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00000077e0280000)
    /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000003000000000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00000077e01e0000)
```

```
plocate 1.1.15
Copyright 2020 Steinar H. Gunderson
License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

updatedb (plocate) 1.1.15
Copyright (C) 2007 Red Hat, Inc. All rights reserved.
This software is distributed under the GPL v.2.

This program is provided with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add which software distro you got your build of plocate from. And if you have reproduced it on the latest version, and reported the problem to an issue tracker where it is maintained.  A stray value of the largest 32 bit unsigned number (or -1 signed) is suspect, maybe some value is uninitialized, but debugging it will take specific knowledge of its code.

Comment: Does this happen to be a proot environment under Termux?

Comment: @GrishaLevit It was yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR this is due to a limitation in Android/[termux/proot](https://github.com/termux/proot) but is trivially worked around with a code change in plocate, which is in the [1.1.20](https://git.sesse.net/?p=plocate;a=blobdiff;f=NEWS;h=bf23f9511cc82fed6ee195ca78d739938d9c3442;hp=03bfceeac30907ce57068ac348a3cccbfd156ffd;hb=64d41711c1da80e0d3d9a15d8ec5a0ef1b5a471f;hpb=5ec2c6351190ea686421da01ae83b5aeca4aa964) release.

`4294967295` (i.e. `0xffffffff`) is `(uint32_t)-1`. This is the value plocate's updatedb uses as a sentinel version number to detect an incompletely written database file.

When plocate's updatedb is generating a database, it first writes out a header block using dummy values (including the bad version number above).

After writing the rest of the database, it goes back to overwrite the header, this time using the correct values (including the correct version value, presently `1`).

Since the database output stream is writing to an unlinked file (opened with `O_TMPFILE`), the file must now be linked at its actual path.

The [code](https://git.sesse.net/?p=plocate;a=blob;f=database-builder.cpp;h=419e012ca94c2625471680de17b67f07716ecec8;hb=HEAD#l681) is roughly:

```c
/* Open database */
fd = open(path.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_TMPFILE, 0640);
outfp = fdopen(fd, "wb");
/* Write dummy header. */
...
/* Write database. */
...
/* Write real header */
fseek(outfp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&hdr, sizeof(hdr), 1, outfp);
/* Link database path */
snprintf(procpath, sizeof(procpath), "/proc/self/fd/%d", fileno(outfp));
linkat(AT_FDCWD, procpath, AT_FDCWD, outfile.c_str(), AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW);

fclose(outfp);
```

This is being executed on Android, which does not allow unprivileged hard link creation, so the `linkat` above would normally fail.

However, it is executing under `proot`, which is implementing a [handler](https://github.com/termux/proot/commit/f42658803833b0840abf6c96ff214a0742229c1f) for `linkat(..., "/proc/X/fd/Y", ..., AT_SYMLINK_FOLLOW)` when, as in this case, the FD is for an unlinked file.

The `linkat` "works" because proot's handler *copies the contents* of the unlinked file, *at the time of the `linkat` call*.  This may be better than nothing, but any further writes to the original file descriptor do not make it in to the file on the filesystem.

In the case of `updatedb`, there are no further writes -- but neither is there an `fflush` between the final `fwrite` and the `linkat` call.  The lack of `fflush` would normally be fine, as the subsequent `fclose` flushes the output buffers. However, with proot's `linkat` implementation this pattern leads to data loss.

There doesn't seem to be a public bug tracker but I've reported this to the <s>ptrace</s> plocate author. Adding an `fflush` would resolve the issue and be harmless otherwise. **Update:** resolved in [994819b](https://git.sesse.net/?p=plocate;a=commit;h=994819bafa9d04be683130433a3f57e08e08422c).

Comment: "I've reported this to the ptrace author", did you mean "proot author"? I saw that you submitted a fix for plocate, but couldn't this also be fixed by proot performing the flush? If so, was also a fix submitted to proot?

Comment: Sorry you're right, meant to say "plocate author". I'm not sure it's possible to fix in proot since afaict it's only intercepting syscalls, it doesn't have access to the userspace stdio buffers.

Comment: You are right, I assumed that `linkat` was passed a file description (which then could be flushed). But that is not the case.

Comment: Awesome work, @GrishaLevit! :-)